# Finding condition based values from more than one table using group by clause in Mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have 2 tables as

```
`timezone_detail` (
     `timezone_detail_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `abbreviation` VARCHAR(6) DEFAULT NULL,
     `time_start` BIGINT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `time_zone_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL
 )
 `time_zone` (                                    
     `time_zone_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `timezone_name` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
     `country_code` VARCHAR(5) DEFAULT NULL
  )
```

I applied query as

```
SELECT z.country_code,tz.abbreviation,tz.time_start
FROM `time_zone` z
 LEFT JOIN `timezone_detail` tz ON z.time_zone_id = tz.time_zone_id

country_code    abbreviation    time_start
AE                LMT          -2147483648
AE                LMT          -2147397248
AE                GST          -1577936472
AF                AFT          -2147483648
AF                AFT          -2147397248
AF                AFT          -788932800
IN                IST          -872058600
IN                IST          -862637400
IN                IST          -764145000


after using **GROUP BY tz.country_code** it gives all first record as
AE  LMT -2147483648
AF  AFT -2147483648
IN  IST -872058600

but I want records with maximum time_start in each group as 

AE  GST -1577936472
AF  AFT -788932800
IN  IST -764145000
```

please help o find these records. thanks

Answer (score 0):

use the having clause:

```
SELECT z.country_code, tz.abbreviation, MIN(tz.time_start) as time_start
    FROM time_zone z LEFT JOIN timezone_detail tz ON z.time_zone_id = tz.time_zone_id
    GROUP BY tz.country_code HAVING MIN(tz.time_start)
```

Comment: `tz.abbreviation` in group by missing

Comment: @Justin this is not require and use doing the group by on `country_code`

Comment: @AnkitKumar use the MIN instead of the MAX. as I have see your requirement.

Comment: No No.. same result is coming. these functions are not working here.

Comment: @AnkitKumar I have updated the answer. check that and let me know.

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
   SELECT z.country_code,
          tz.abbreviation,
          tz.time_start
   FROM time_zone z 
   LEFT JOIN timezone_detail tz ON z.time_zone_id = tz.time_zone_id
   JOIN (SELECT z.country_code, tz.abbreviation, MAX(tz.time_start) time_start
         FROM time_zone z 
         LEFT JOIN timezone_detail tz ON z.time_zone_id = tz.time_zone_id
         GROUP BY z.country_code, tz.abbreviation ) a
    ON z.country_code = a.country_code 
          tz.abbreviation =a.abbreviation 
          tz.time_start = a.time_start
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY z.country_code,tz.abbreviation ORDER BY tz.time_start DESC) AS rnk' at line 2

Comment: hi Justinn, thanks for your reply. But this is not working inmy case. above is the error.